# SSO .NET thick client with Java server via TCP using Kerberos

Tags: java, .net, security, tcp, kerberos

I intend to have .NET thick clients running inside a Windows domain connect to a Java server via a straight TCP connection (protocol will be custom Google Protocol Buffer messages). I'm looking at how I can authenticate these clients without requiring further credentials be entered by the users (in other words, support single sign-on).

My initial thinking was to use Kerberos, but I'm not even certain that it's possible or ultimately secure over straight TCP. Can anyone comment on this? Is it possible? Are there any examples out there of how to achieve this, both client-side and server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos doesn't run over 'straight TCP'. It uses an encryption protocol. See the JGSS-API, built into the JRE.